# in Angular inside ngtemplateoutlet unable to access formcontrol of form control name

Tags: angular, form-control, formgroups, ng-template, ngtemplateoutlet

i create stackblitz project

https://stackblitz.com/edit/new-project-jksckf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fform-field-overview-example.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fform-field-overview-example.html

If i pass formcontrolname to ng-template using ngtemplateoutlet it is  showing Error

## if i use formControlName i am getting this error

Console was cleared
ERROR
Error: formControlName must be used with a parent formGroup directive. You'll want to add a formGroup
directive and pass it an existing FormGroup instance (you can create one in your class).

Example:

`<div [formGroup]="myGroup">

`
In your class:

`this.myGroup = new FormGroup({ firstName: new FormControl() });` 
if i use formControl i am getting another error..

i need to dynamicaly pass the formcontrolname

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the own control

```
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="dynamicCtrl;
            context:{data:{control:testForm.controls?.age,label:'Age'}}">
</ng-container>

<ng-template #dynamicCtrl let-data="data">
  <label>{{data.label}}</label>
  <input [formControl]="data.control" />
</ng-template>
```

If you has a variable

```
field="age"
```

You can use

```
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="dynamicCtrl;
            context:{data:{control:testForm.get(field),label:'Age'}}">
</ng-container>
```